# Pass target of function within the parameters of function itself

Tags: jquery

I apologize for the confusing title; I'm hoping an example will help clarify things.

```
$(".element").functionName({
    option1:true,
    doneFunc: function(){
        thisElem = $(this);
        functionName2(thisElem);
    }
});
```

I'm trying to pass the specific instance of ".element" to to functionName2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the element as a variable before running the callback.

Example:

```
var $element = $(".element");
$element.functionName({
    option1:true,
    doneFunc: function(){
        functionName2($element);
    }
});
```

This will "save the element" inside the variable $element, so you can use it inside a function.

The scoping in Javascript is in function level. This means that functions defined in a given scope will have access to the environment where it is defined. By this we know that `doneFunc` will have access to the `$element` variable. This inside functions is often referred to as ["lexical closure"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)

---

If you have multiple elements I think the best way is to iterate over them yout self.

For instance:

```
 $('.element').each(function() {
     var $element = $(this);
     $element.functionName({
         option1:true,
         doneFunc: function(){
             functionName2($element);
         }
     });
 });
```

Here we see the lexical closure in use.

Comment: I appreciate the response, the problem is that there are multiple divs with the element class and I need to pass the elements one at a time. I tried this out and it passed all instances of ".element".

Comment: As long as the plugin (as I assume you use?) does not provide the element it self, I think the best way is to iterate over the elements your self. I'll update my answer to show an example.